# Find all formulas and drag them down (FillDown) to a certain row number skipping cells that have values in them?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I'm trying to use FillDown to make all formulas be pulled down to a certain row skipping over cells that have a value in them...

If we look at the example:

[image: Example]

In both column C and E there are formulas and in C6 we've overridden the cell with the value of 15.

If we were in row 5 and I wanted the code to drag the formula down 5 lines it would need to take the formula in C5 and because C6 has a value it would skip this one and instead place it into C7 and drag it down.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the column and if the cell is empty then copy the formula from the first cell?

Like this?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> C2 Which I am assuming will have a formula
        Set rng = .Cells(2, 3)

        For i = 3 To lRow 
            If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "" Then rng.Copy .Cells(i, 3)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**Note**: For your case, please amend it as needed.

**EDIT**

I would highly recommend @Captains Non VBA way as shown above. Here is the code, just in case someone is looking for a VBA option.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range, blnkRng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> C2 Which I am assuming will have a formula
        Set rng = .Cells(2, 3)

        On Error Resume Next
        Set blnkRng = .Range("C3:C" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not blnkRng Is Nothing Then rng.Copy blnkRng
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The second way using what @Captain said works by far the best way, it works pretty good. I've made a few changes and could do with some more but im not quite sure how to do it... Basically, I've done the following at one point: `Set Rng = Range("N2:O2")` and ideally I'd like to do something like: `Set Rng = Range("A1:O" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` but for it to only find the first formula in each column and then only copy the formulas down the columns IF they have a formula in...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go the VBA route, you can do it with built-in features:

1. Copy the cell with the formula
2. Highlight the target range including populated cells (e.g. whole column)
3. On the Home Ribbon, under Editing, Find & Select open up "Go To Special"
4. Choose "Blanks" in the popup and click OK
5. The selection will be updated to only the blank cells so then you can paste

There are a few other useful things in that "Go To Special" box too!

Comment: + 1 Damn! I had totally forgotten about this one :D

Answer (score 0):

To do it with code (assuming you want to copy down to say row 10):

Range("C3:C10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).FormulaR1C1 = Range("C2").FormulaR1C1